# Multiple Angular validators work independently, but not together

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I've written two validation directives. Each one works fine individually, but when both are applied, numberValidator fails anytime rangeValidator fails (so, because "3" fails rangeValidator, it fails numberValidator as well, even though it passes when rangeValidator is out of the picture).

Logging verifies that the numberValidator is indeed failing (vs some error in HTML).

I would have expected the directives to function independently of one another -- I don't want the user to enter "3" and still see "Must be a number."

Using a number input is not an option.

My JS:

```
app.directive('rangeValidator', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var min = scope.$eval(attrs.minValue);
            var max = scope.$eval(attrs.maxValue);
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (parseInt(viewValue) >= min && parseInt(viewValue) <= max) {
                    // it is valid
                    ctrl.$setValidity('rangeValidator', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                    ctrl.$setValidity('rangeValidator', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});


app.directive('numberValidator', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                if (!isNaN(parseInt(viewValue))) {
                    // it is valid
                    console.log('Number Validator passed!');
                    ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
                    ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', false);
                    return undefined;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've followed the Angular docs' advice and returned `undefined` for invalid values within your parser function. The problem with doing that (in your case) is that it breaks the parsers pipeline: the directive that first detects an invalid value will pass `undefined` to the next one, which will obviously deem it invalid as well.

I can think of two solutions:

**1) Let the original value flow through the parsers pipeline:**

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
    if (parseInt(viewValue) >= min && parseInt(viewValue) <= max) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('rangeValidator', true);
    } else {
        ctrl.$setValidity('rangeValidator', false);
    }
    return viewValue;
});

...

ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(viewValue))) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', true);
    } else {    
        ctrl.$setValidity('numberValidator', false);
    }
    return viewValue;
});
```

Working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sK88K2LLFHHR3ZWYQR6F?p=preview).

This won't prevent the model from being updated with invalid values, and you'll need to use the `$valid` or `$invalid` properties to check the field state before using its value, but you'll be able to check errors independently of each other.

**2) Set different priorities to both directives**

You can control the order the directives are executed by setting different priorities to each one, and by doing so you can check for invalid values in an incremental way, like this:

```
<span ng-show="form.value.$error.rangeValidator">Invalid range</span>
<span ng-show="!form.value.$error.rangeValidator && form.value.$error.numberValidator">Invalid number</span>
```

Working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/giYkif?p=preview).

It comes with a caveat: it may become very messy as more validations are added.

Personally I like the first approach better, even though it doesn't prevent the model from being updated with invalid values.

Comment: My aim was to avoid updating the model (checking field state was going to get tiresome quickly in this case), so I appreciate the dual approach. Thanks!